# How to an Add to cart Button to a Content Type?

Tags: 7, ubercart, commerce

Is there a possibility to show add to cart button in node page.

**Requirment:**

1. Node will be created along with price
2. Add to cart button needed in that content type
3. Users can click on "Add to cart" button
4. Then ask for the payment like credit card, paypal.

I dont want a huge functionality like [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) does. No products, products sku.

Any suggestions or any ideas about how to get this to work?

Comment: You tagged drupal commerce and Ubercart.  Is your project made with the 1rst or the 2nd one solution ?

Comment: I had not yet chosen which one yet. If you can suggest it would be really helpful.

Comment: `Is there a possibility to show add to cart button in node page.  No products, products sku.` What exactly are you selling?

Comment: I am doing a rental website. So people can rent a product and after some time/day they will return back. And then will make the product available from Admin

Comment: Questions asking for modules are off topic, because of the poor answers they encourage (see below, you have a list of links to modules, and no actual **answer** to the question) - if you'd like this re-opened, please edit that part out of the question, and **add information about what you've already tried**. Your last couple of questions have just been a list of requirements, that are going to be too unique to _your_ situation to be useful to future visitors. Take some time to provide **quality** content, and you'll get some quality response. Thanks in advance for your cooperation

Comment: Hi Clive, I had a question about how to implement that functionality and even I had narrowed my query. Then I am not sure what else people can ask here? This is for sharing knowledge, if anybody knows the answer or they had implemented already, they will reply. I don't think I asked a question that is not related. Thanks for putting hold two of my queries.

Comment: Take a look at the answers - how many different approaches are outlined there? I can see 3, without any explanation of how any of them can actually be used to solve the problem. It's a vague problem, with vague solutions, which is no good for Q+A I'm afraid. This is where we differ massively from support forums/reddit/other platforms you might be used to. We want narrowly-scoped, specific, high-quality content questions, that have a single objective answer. And we're not shy about enforcing that - the success of the Stack Exchange model is widely apparent, we're not going to change it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are 2 possible alternatives for setting up a simple shopping cart without using the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) or [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) modules (as in your "*I don't want a huge functionality like Drupal commerce does. No products, products sku.*").

## Option 1: A lightweight e-shop

If you're only looking for a simple and lightweight e-commerce solution, have a looking at the [Light Shop](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightshop) module (for D7, not for D6, not (yet?) for D8). Here is a quote from its project page:

> - Session-stored basket.
> - Adding to basket and its subsequent editing/checkout process is done using AJAX. Also it works fine when JavaScript is turned off.
> - Node based shopping. As the product can be assigned to any node type. One or more. With full support Field API features (regarding nodes).
> - Orders history. For each order will be created a separate node.
> - There is no dependence on other modules.
> - Full support for working with anonymous users
> - Integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

## Option 2: A simple shopping cart

If you're only looking for a shopping cart, have a looking at the [Basic Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) module (for D7, not for D6, not (yet?) for D8). Here is a quote from its project page:

> Basic cart is a very simple shopping cart / checkout process for Drupal, that just sends 2 emails after each order. Along with the shopping cart, this module also provides a block where you can view your cart's content. It's ideal for small websites with only a few products or other content types being sold, for example touristic offers.
>
> **Main difference from Ubercart and Commerce:**
>
> The main difference from Ubercart and Commerce is the possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart. It also doesn't bother you with the Product SKU, that can be a pain when you have just a few products.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - The possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart.
> - The possibility of sending, or not, an email to the customer once an order is placed.
> - Custom email messages for both the site administrator and the customer, along with the order details.
> - Order registration and listing in the administration area using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
> - Integration with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.
> - A block with the contents of your shopping cart.

Here is a screenshot of it (note the "**Checkout**" button also ...):

[image]

**Note**: According to "[Payment/Basic Cart integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1541916)" it *should be possible* to integrate this module with the [Payment](https://www.drupal.org/project/payment) module. Though that integration is still outstanding. So while waiting for that to ever get delivered, it looks like you'll have to investigate yourself to what extend this Payment module is usable in your case without that integration. As an alternative: contact the module owner to see what kind of sponsorship may get it delivered soom.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre. basic_cart module is exactly what I need. But it doesn't have payment integration. Can we have that either??

Comment: Have a look at my note I just added. I think for Basic cart this is currently "as good as it gets".

Comment: @Nagarjuna : merci (oeps: thank you) for the accept! Next question?

Answer (score 0):

SO, if you actually use drupal commerce, it separates products from product displays and it's really easy to add the 'add to cart form' to your product displays.

So, if you install the Drupal commerce module you will be able to define product type nodes. However, these will not automatically display, you need to create product display nodes. To these, you can add an add to cart form "out of box." There's a few reasons for doing it this way, but more than anything it gives you more control over presentation, product variations and so on.

So, you need to 1) install Drupal commerce; 2) add some products and create their product displays; 3) and your "add to cart form" to the product displays.

From there you can build views of your product displays for a catalogue, just remember to add the relationship back to the products themselves. There's a lot of good YouTube tutorials on how to get started with Drupal commerce

Comment: Could you perhaps expand your answer a bit with a step-by-step explanation? This is can be pretty vague for the OP.

Comment: Hi @nizz0k, can you please explain a bit more, so that I can give a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [MoneySuite](https://www.drupal.org/project/moneysuite) **Pay per view** might do.

> Sell Access to Individual Nodes and Content.

Since MoneySuite is a fork of [MoneyScripts](https://www.moneyscripts.net/drupal-pay-per-view). Here are more details:

> This module allows you to sell access to individual nodes, so that
>   users will have to pay before they can see the full node. This allows
>   you to easily monetize any content without having to worry about
>   memberships or roles. Users can purchase access to as few or as many
>   nodes as they want. **You can specify what should be shown to users who
>   do not have access, using custom text and node tokens.** You can set
>   default prices for a content-type, and then override them in the
>   individual node settings. The whole setup is very flexible, and is a
>   great way to monetize your site. Think 'Pay Per View', and you're on
>   the right track. Some possible uses for Premium Nodes include 'Pay to
>   View Complete Answer', 'Pay for Access to this Video', etc. Also, you
>   can charge for access to individual Fields in a node with the new
>   Drupal 7 Fields system. This allows for a very powerful and very
>   flexible system. Get it to work just how you need.

Comment: Interesting ...!